# Settlement Amount of Razorpay Dashboard is not correct

Tags: node.js, web, stripe-payments, payment, razorpay

I am using razorpay payments pages and webhooks to calculate store the payment information to my own database. I see there are three fields that are being returned by it(the webhook), the `payment amount`, `the fees`, and `the tax`. From what I could gather from the documentation, the final settled amount that is received by the business owner is calculated as follows: `payment amount - fees - tax`. However when I try to make a test payment and make this calculation and check my settlements dashboard on razorpay, it doesn't add up. The `amount - fees - tax  !=  amount shown on razorpay dashboard`
Can anyone help me with this? I am attaching an example payload below that razorpay webhook pushes.

Example payload from razorpay docs

```
{
  "entity":"event",
  "account_id":"acc_DLXfTGFm2PS7Cy",
  "event":"payment.captured",
  "contains":[
    "payment"
  ],
  "payload":{
    "payment":{
      "entity":{
        "id":"pay_DORWaWz6UGwvRx",
        "entity":"payment",
        "amount":70000,
        "currency":"INR",
        "status":"captured",
        "order_id":"order_DORWL4a5PvwmiR",
        "invoice_id":null,
        "international":false,
        "method":"upi",
        "amount_refunded":0,
        "refund_status":null,
        "captured":true,
        "description":null,
        "card_id":null,
        "bank":null,
        "wallet":null,
        "vpa":"sauravkumar@exampleupi",
        "email":"saurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact":"+919998887776",
        "notes":{
          "participant_name":"Saurav Kumar",
          "email":"saurav.kumar@example.com",
          "phone":"9998887776"
        },
        "fee":1652,
        "tax":252,
        "error_code":null,
        "error_description":null,
        "created_at":1569853622
      }
    }
  },
  "created_at":1569853628
}
```

Comment: Without your code for the payment integration, it is impossible to help you debug.